# Как в MS SQL заменить значение в узле XML?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server

Я знаю, что есть `replace value of`, но происходит замена значение всего узла.

Можно ли добиться поведения, как у обычного Replace MS SQL ?

Т.е я указываю значение, которое будет заменено при совпадении, а не совпавшая часть останется без изменений.

Или обязательно нужно считать значение в переменную вызвать стандартный SQL Replace, а потом засунуть это значение в XML?

Comment: _"нужно считать значение в переменную вызвать стандартный SQL Replace, а потом засунуть это значение в XML"_ - похоже, что так. Хотя в [working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xpath-functions-20040723/) XQuery, который лежит в основе реализации XQuery-процессора SqlServer и присутствует `fn:replace`, однако, SqlServer поддерживает довольно [ограниченный](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189254.aspx) набор строковых функций.